# You flip a coin four times. First flip is heads. What are the chances that at least three of the four flips will be heads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Wondering if my work is correct.

2^4 = 16

Successful attempts to get at least three heads: HHHH, HHHT, THHH, HTHH, HHTH = 5

5/16 is my answer.  I just wanted to make sure this was correct.  Thank you.

Comment: How did you take into account the "first flip is head" condition?

Comment: As an aside, manually listing the outcomes out is fine for small examples and to help build intuition, but you should get out of that bad habit sooner rather than later.  If the question was about flipping a coin a thousand times and asking for the chances of having flipped at least 600 heads, you do *not* want to be writing them out by hand.

Comment: Yeah, like David said below.  I am going to work on the formula so I can better understand the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your answer is not correct.  First, note that you included THHH as a "success," but that case violates your condition that "First flip is heads."

*Given* that the first flip is heads, there are only $2^3 = 8$ equally likely scenarios:

HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HHTT, HTHH, HTHT, HTTH, and HTTT.

Now do your counting...

Comment: Ok. So 4/16=1/4?  Since there are only four scenarios that would have at least three heads in the four flips.

Comment: @Peterrobinson Effectively, since we were told that the first flip was a head we can ignore that it ever happened.  The conditional probability that we flip at least three heads out of four flips given the first flip was heads is exactly the same as the unconditional probability that we flip at least two heads out of three flips.  We have effectively reduced the sample space size down from $2^4$ to only $2^3$.

Comment: Ok.  So because there are only three flips now.  2^3 = 8    HHHH, HHHT, HTHH, HHTH = 4.  4/8=1/2

Comment: That is one way of thinking about it, yes.  The other way which you should also become comfortable with is directly via the definition of conditional probability.  $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$

Comment: @Peterrobinson:  I'm just wondering whether you're going to upvote or accept my answer which supercedes all these comments...

Comment: Yeah, I struggle with probability questions sometimes.  Using the formula would be better since it will help for future problems and to understand the material better.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the first flip is heads, you wind up with at least three heads in all if and only if the majority of the final three flips come up heads. For any set of odd flips (such as three), the majority is either heads or tails with equal probability, namely $1/2$.